# Как в JavaScript в регулярном выражении получить все остальное отличное от совпадения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка `abc123/abc123/abc123`
Мне нужно получить последние символы после знака `/`, я это делаю с помощью регулярки `/[^\/]*$/g`.
Но как мне можно получить остальное (т.е. всё до последнего встречающегося символа `/`)?
В идеале хочется единую регулярку с группами показывающую результат:

```
group1: abc123/abc123
group2: abc123
```

Пробовал написать что-то наподобие `(\w+\/*)*([^\/]*$)`, но она возвращает всю строку и последние нужные символы

Comment: А почему вы не пробовали `.replace`  с вашим регулярным выражением? `replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, '')`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew была такая идея, но в моем случае нужно именно разделение на две группы, реплейс же всегда вернет единичный результат

Comment: Тогда самы простой шаблон [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1308656/182013).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая эффективнее, результаты в первой и второй группах.
Вторая находит 2 вхождения.

```js
console.log("abc123/def123/qwe123".match(/^(.*)\/([^/]*)$/))
console.log("abc123/def123/qwe123".match(/([^/]|\/(?=.*\/))+/g))
```

Answer (score 2):

> В идеале хочется единую регулярку с группами показывающую результат:
>
> ```
> group1: abc123/abc123  
> group2: abc123
> ```

```js
const re = /(.*)\/([^/]+)?$/, 
      [, group1, group2 = ''] = 'abc123/def456/ghi789'.match(re); 
console.log({ group1, group2 });
```

**upd.:** Скорректировал для обработки случаев с завершающим `/` (теперь, в таких случаях, строка до этого завершающего слэша попадет в первую группу, а вторая будет соотв. пустой).

Comment: Стоит учитывать, что деструктуризация предполагает совпадение с регуляркой - иначе будет брошена ошибка. То есть, в реальном коде надо либо предварительно проверять результат `match` перед его деструктуризацией, либо обрабатывать возможную ошибку в `try..catch` (оба варианта одинаково применимы, каждый из них удобен в своих случаях: явная проверка более очевидна, но и бросание ошибки иногда помогает значительно упростить логику).

Comment: Вместо проверки можно сделать `|| []` - тоже довольно компактно.

Comment: Кстати, лучше прям в ответе написать, а не в комментарии.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, `|| [<something>]` удобно для задания fallback-значений с пропуском ошибок. То есть, это несколько другой принцип обработки исключительных ситуаций (иногда при ошибке надо подставить дефолтное значение, а иногда - прекратить выполнение). Вопрос был задан все-таки о рег.выражении, поэтому замечаниям о нюансах (деструктуризации и обработке ошибок) место именно в комментариях, ящитаю. Регулярку можно очень по-разному использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один из вариантов:

```js
const str = 'abc123/abc123/abc123';

const [group1, group2] = str.split(/\/(?=[^/]*$)/);

console.log(group1);
console.log(group2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```js
console.log("abc123/def123/qwe123".match(/(.*)\/(.*)/))
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/6pj9XQ/1).

**Подробности**

- `(.*)` - Группа (подмаска) №1: ноль и более символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно больше (т.е. всё от начала до последнего вхождения последующих шаблонов в выражении)
- `\/` - символ `/`
- `(.*)` - Группа (подмаска) №2: ноль и более символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно больше (т.е. оставшаяся часть строки).